# How to handle refresh while using iFrame in page structure

Tags: html, iframe, page-refresh

[image]

This is my web structure. In which all link contents are opened in iFrame when link is clicked.

Say I have clicked on 1st link (not Home page) , **it gets open in iFrame**,contents are displayed properly,all ok. But as I press **refresh button** expected is shlould load same page whose link I have clicked,but instead of that it loads Home page.

**How should I be on same page after refresh also?**

I'm using php for server side scripting. Thanks!

**Edit:**
I tried to store visited page name in session variable and then while loading Home page I check like

```
$_Session['visited']='/pages/neworder.html';

if(isset($_Session['visited']))
{
  echo "<script>window.location.href=</script>".$_Session['visited'];
}
```

But didnt work!

Answer (score 0):

Server side: Link sends GET request to the page and the src of the iFrame is set by the server.

-OR-

Client side: Add onclick function on the links which changes the src atribute for example with the following code:

```
document.getElementById('Iframe').src="new link";
```

-OR-

```
<iframe src="startin_link" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
<p><a href="some_link" target="iframe_a">link</a></p>
```

Pure html.

EDIT: If you want to stay in the page... I suggest you use the first option. Example:

```
<a href='?page=1'>Some link</a>
```

then on server side:

```
if(!is_null($_GET['page'])){
     $iframeLink=arrayOfLinks[$_GET['page']];
}else{
     $iframeLink="Starting Link";
}
```

and the iFrame should look like this:

```
<iframe src='<?php echo  $iframeLink; ?>'></iframe>
```

Comment: oh. Thanks,will try this and will update on this. Thanks for quick replay.

Comment: when Click on link, I have passed ?page=mypage. But always getting redirected to Starting link in iFrame, & when echo $_GET['page'] says Undefined index

Comment: can you show me the 'mypage' variable and the way you implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is with Jquery. If you make your website use anchors, for example 
http://yoursite.com/#page-example

```
<a href="#page-example">example</a>
```

When you refresh the page, you will still be accessing this anchor. With jquery you can get this value and do some stuff based on that. So!

```
var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
```

This will get that # value, you can compare that in javascript then, or use a switch to determine what to do or simulate the page change.